# Package Installation Error - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The error occurs when I'm trying to create ADO.NET Entity Data Model. The error says:

> The preinstalled packages have a reference to a missing Registry
>   value. Could not find a Registry key with name
>   'EntityFrameworkVisualStudio14Tools' under 
>   'SOFTWARE\NuGet\Repositoty'.

I'm using Windows 10, Visual Studio 2015, and tried to install Entity Framework 6.1.3

Comment: check your references,/ show code

Answer (score 5):

I wasted a whole weekend on this issue.  I ended up resolving it by going into the registry under \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\NuGet\Repository and made a new key titled EntityFrameworkVisualStudio14Tools and set the data value to 1.  Hope this keeps other people from wasting a bunch of time like I did.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the string `EntityFrameworkVisualStudio15Tools` was missing but instead `EntityFrameworkVisualStudio16Tools` was there. I guess because I also installed Visual Studio 2019, but I'm currently working in Visual Studio 2017.
Registry Path on a 64 bit Windows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Nuget\Repository
```

Solution:
I created the string `EntityFrameworkVisualStudio15Tools` and copied the value from `EntityFrameworkVisualStudio16Tools` which was in my case:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Entity Framework Tools\NuGet Packages\
```

Answer (score 1):

> The preinstalled packages have a reference to a missing Registry value. Could not find a Registry key with name 'EntityFrameworkVisualStudio15Tools' under 'SOFTWARE\NuGet\Repository'.

I had this problem, I solved this way:

1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/install-nuget#nuget-package-manager-in-visual-studio

2 - Install it again and choose the package for your framework (Individual Components)

3 - I haven't tried this but you can try to install only the individual components for your framework.

I used the second option and it worked with me.

Comment: Number #3 worked for me with VS 2022.  The registry error started after I uninstalled an older version of VS. The "Repair" option did nothing.  However, after uninstalling and then reinstalling the packages everything worked normally again. +1

Answer (score 0):

Need to add a value in registry editor [Video on solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tbBTY7UuaG8&ab_channel=winforms)