# Entity Framework Model Generation Error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2017

Im using visual studio 2017, and trying to generate a data model for an existing database, and I get below error. Tried with both EF 5 and EF 6, but same error.[image]

Found below answer on stackoverflow and tried reinstalling EF via package manager console but it did not solved the issue.

[Package Installation Error - Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436769/package-installation-error-entity-framework?rq=1)

Searched for an answer on this but was unsuccessful. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is the target .NET Framework version of your projects? Which VS version do you have? Do you used EF 6.2?

Comment: This isn't related to EF NuGet packages. Did you install the Data storage and processing workload when installing VS2107?

Comment: @ChW - Yes, I used EF 6.2.0

Comment: @Gert Arnold  Yes, I did install Data storage and processing workload when installing VS 2017

Answer (score 0):

This was working in VS 2017, but today only I got to know that I get this error when edmx is generated from DB.
As I solution I repaired VS 2017, but did not work.
Finally, uninstalled an reinstalled VS 2017 and now its working. But Im yet to install VS 2017 - 15.6.4 update on the new VS installation. 
Thanks all for the help.