# The error occurs when I'm trying to create ADO.NET Entity Data Mods:el. The error say

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, nuget-package, registrykey

The preinstalled packages have a reference to a missing Registry value. Could not find a Registry key with name 'EntityFrameworkVisualStudio16Tools' under 'SOFTWARE\NuGet\Repositoty'.

Comment: What is the Visual Studio version that you're using? Have you tried solutions from here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436769/package-installation-error-entity-framework

Comment: i am using vs19 and now my issue is solved i was doing something wrong which is fixed now.thank u for the support..happy coding :)